# How to create a new jupyter notebook cell and update the cell using notebook server rest api's or python code?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am new to python coding.I am able to create the new .ipynb file using the jupyter notebook server rest api's.

I am using the below curl command to create a new .ipynb file using the rest api's,

```
curl -X PUT "http://localhost:8890/api/contents/two.ipynb" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Authorization: Token xxxxxxxx" -d "{\"name\": \"one.ipynb\"}"
```

Now, I am trying to create a new jupyter notebook cell using jupyter notebook server rest api's or using python code and updating the cell with basic print statement. But not able to get. Does anybody know how to solve this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I completed the task with the following code:
creating new notebook:

```
import requests
import nbformat as nbf
import sys
from nbconvert.preprocessors import ExecutePreprocessor
import json
import os

def create_nb():
  api_url =  'http://192.168.1.xxx:8890/api/contents/root/ppl'
  headers = {'token': 'token_passwd'}
  headers1 = {'Authorization': 'Token token_passwd'}
  body={"type": "notebook"}

  result = requests.post(api_url,headers=headers1,json=body)
  output=result.json()
  return('/'+output["path"])
```

creating a new cell in specified path:

```
def create_cell(path,session_id):

  head,file_name = os.path.split(path)
  file_path=path[1:]
  api_url =  'http://192.168.1.126:8890/api/sessions/'+session_id
  headers1 = {'Authorization': 'Token token_passwd','ContentType': 'application/json'}
  body={"name":file_name, "type": "notebook","path":   file_path,"kernel": {"name": "python3"}}
  # result = requests.post(api_url,headers=headers1,json=body)

  present_id=requests.get(api_url,headers=headers1)
  # print("present_id ---->>> "+present_id.json()["id"])
  nb1 = nbf.read(path, as_version=4)
  code=""""""
  nb1['cells']= nb1['cells']+[nbf.v4.new_code_cell(code)]
  with open(path, "w") as f:
    nbf.write(nb1, f)

  return("cell created")
```

Comment: Is there any rest api to run cell that you made ???

Comment: To create a new Notebook you should use PUT method.

Answer (score 0):

```
def write_file_remotely(self, filename):
    """Creates a new .remote ipynb file which will be used for testing."""
    # https://jupyter-server.readthedocs.io/en/latest/developers/rest-api.html#put--api-contents-path
    notebook_file_name = os.path.basename(filename)
    body = {
        "content": {
            "cells": [{
                "cell_type": "code",
                "execution_count": 1,
                "metadata": {},
                "outputs": [],
                "source": ['print("Hello Notebooks!")']
            }],
            "metadata": {},
            "nbformat": 4,
            "nbformat_minor": 4
        },
        "format": "json",
        "name": f"{notebook_file_name}",
        "path": f"{notebook_file_name}",
        "type": "notebook",
    }
    # pylint: enable=g-inconsistent-quotes
    print(f'Creating a new Notebook file: {notebook_file_name}')
    print(body)
    try:
      # Check: c.ServerApp.disable_check_xsrf setting.      
      response = self._session.put(
          f'{self.url}/api/contents/{notebook_file_name}',
          timeout=HTTP_TIMEOUT_SESSION,
          auth=BearerAuth(self._token),         
          json=body)
      response.raise_for_status()
      return True
    except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as err:
      print(response.status_code)
      http_code = err.response.status_code
      if http_code == 404:
        print(f'{self.url} HTTP: {http_code}')
    return False
```